# Cordova / Phonegap Wifi event connection with SSID

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Is there an event on a particular wifi ssid ?
Because i need to know when a specific SSID is connected to the device because I've never read anything about this...

(For Android And iOS)

thanks you for your Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard Cordova Network Information plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) to register for network connection notifications, and one of several SSID plugins (Matt Parson's Android/iOS plugin at https://github.com/parsonsmatt/WifiWizard is a good one) to retrieve the SSID. So when you get a notification that you're connected via WiFi, go get the SSID and see if it's the one in which you're interested.